# Why is the expected value (mean) of a variable written using square brackets?

Tags: probability, statistics, notation, random-variables

My question is told in a few words: Why do you write $E[X]$ in square brackets instead of something like $E(X)$? Probably it is not a "function". How would you call it then? This question also applies for $Var[X]$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mathematicians usually adopt square bracket such that $f[g]$, instead of $f(g)$ to indicate $f$ is a functional. Obviously, random variable $X=X(\omega)$ is a function, which makes expectation, variance and so on functionals. But this is only an unestablished convention, not necessary.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "$f$ is a functional" when also stating that expectation and variance are functionals? It sounds to me like: "Yes, $f[g]$ shall not be confused with $f(g)$ but essentially it is the same."

Comment: @Tobias $f$ is to $g$ what $E$ is to $X$. And yes, both () and [] are of the same meaning with different styles.

Comment: "Mathematicians usually adopt square bracket such that f[g], instead of f(g) to indicate f is a functional." Any reference for this?

Comment: @Did Probably nope. We write $f[g(x)]$ instead of $f(g(x))$ for a good writing style. And usually we don't care about $x$ in a functional so just ignore it together with (). This leaves [] there.

Comment: To be frank, I do not understand why you present the use of brackets as a general or standard practice. It is not. "Mathematicians" and "usually" in your answer are both misleading. "We" in your comment is misleading as well--unless you explain who are this "we". (Note that "unestablished convention" is an oxymoron.) @upvoters Care to explain your upvote?

Comment: @Did oh yes, definitely. I'm upvoting because I've confirmed this fact to be true, since $X$ is indeed a mapping from probability to value, so it makes sense. I find it hardly imaginable for this to be just a coincidence.

Comment: For those wondering what a functional is - look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_(mathematics)

Comment: @Did it is indeed common practice, particularly in the context of "calculus of variations" which deals with functionals. I don't know if there is a canonical reference for this notational convention; the one I have in mind where I first came across it where this notational convention was mentioned explicitly, was Bishop's Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning book (which is quite a seminal book in the ML literature).

Answer (score 2):

I don't.

You can write in both ways, it doesn't matter. Some don't even use brackets but might instead write $EX$ or $VX$.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with all the above, but also it might has been inherited by the "brackets notation" used to notate discrete functions. For example, a discrete signal is notated as $x[n]$. Just saying...

Comment: In my experience engineers write $x[n]$, mathematicians write $x_n$.

Answer (score 0):

I too have been in search of this answer recently, ["The use of square brackets was used as a strict mathematical definition of what E really was within its context, E[x], with expectation"](http://tjadclark.com/blog/article/19-why-we-use-e-x-to-denote-expectation)

This may be due to the notion of [polynomial rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring), as it stands to reason that expectation fits the properties of a polynomial ring, Perhaps ergo it's seen as an extension of $\mathbb{R}[X]$, hence E[X] - or potentially $\mathbb{E}[X]$?

I am not a mathematician, perhaps someone could confirm this.

Comment: You should at least summarize the contents of the page linked to, it can go away at any moment.

Comment: Ok thanks vonbrand, I've edited to include reasoning with links to wikipedia - which hopefully shouldn't disappear

Comment: The interpretation of an extension of the polynomial ring notation is pure fantasy.

Comment: Thanks Did, could you perhaps elaborate why Expectation is not a polynomial ring ?

Comment: If it's not known to be correct, sure, I may be incorrect... But that doesn't mean my idea is pure fantasy as you so state, sure I did think it up, but it's probable. i.e not correct, nor incorrect. No discreteness here. Or do you have the answer, thereby proving me incorrect ?

Comment: And just to be completely clear, it's not that expectation is an extension of a polynomial ring, it is a polynomial ring in the context of most statistics. What I mean by an extension of, is that it really is an extension of the set of real numbers.

Comment: lol, and as a matter of fact, the link did go away! thanks for the edit! :)