# Why Square Brackets for Expectation

Tags: soft-question, notation

I've often seen $\mathbb{E}[X]$ instead of $\mathbb{E}(X)$, but it seems variance is almost always $Var(X)$.  E.g., Wikipedia for [Expected Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) and [Variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance).  Is there a good mathematical reason for using square brackets for one and not the other?

Comment: Not entirely sure (I tend personally to use neither parentheses nor brackets whenever possible and non-ambiguous), but I'd say it's arbitrary for a good part. You may also want to look at [this](http://www.quora.com/Why-do-most-people-write-E-X-instead-of-E-X-for-the-expected-value) and [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573148/why-is-the-exptected-value-mean-of-a-variable-written-using-square-brackets).

Comment: I don't think there's a reason other than habit. I've seen both $\mathbb{E}(X)$ and $\mathbb{V}[X]$ "in the wild" for expectation and variance, respectively.

Comment: It's the notation I saw in my probability and stochastics courses in undergrad/grad, so it's what I'm used to. But it's just a matter of preference. Some authors simply write $\mathbb E X$ for expectation.

Answer (score 2):

The random variable $X$ is a *function* whereas the Expectation is a *functional*. Mathematicians adopt the use of square brackets for functionals. This is why.

Comment: By this logic, variance would also be a functional.

Comment: For those wondering what a functional is - look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_(mathematics)